# informatica multi correlated subquery implementation

Tags: sql, subquery, etl, informatica-powercenter

I am facing a task that due to my lack of experience with Informatica Components, in particular SQL Transformation, I did not implemented yet.
So what would be the best approch in PowerCenter to implement this kind of subquery:

```
SELECT
   A.ID,
   NVL2(A.SACHKONTO, B.KLAMMER, A.ID) AS KLAMMER
FROM
Table1 A,
    (SELECT
       A.ID AS KLAMMER,
       B.ID
FROM
    (SELECT
        ID,
        ID AS VON_ID,
        LEAD(ID,1) OVER (ORDER BY ID) - 1 AS BIS_ID
    FROM
        Table1
    WHERE
        SACHKONTO IS NULL) A,
    Table1 B
WHERE
    B.ID BETWEEN A.VON_ID AND A.BIS_ID
) B
WHERE
  A.ID = B.ID
```

So I tried different approch with small successed. 
The first was to "decompose" the SQL in it's small part(I will refer if necessary or edit the question).
I also tried to put the all query (after have adapted it to Informatica SQL "language", but without success.

This is the most close solution that i got to replicate such query, without considerting performance important(I did use an SQL Override in the SQ), but as from the table result, the join is been not propely processed, then I believe I need to add another pipeline to let execute the join in the proper order:

My mapping solution:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put the subquery into a lookup transformation and then match the records coming through from the outer query (which i assume will be what you're putting into your zource qualifier per the A.ID = B.ID from the original query and then filter the nulls later)

Or you could similarly use 2 source qualifiers (one for the parent query and another for the subquery) followed by a joiner transformation with normal join type. This way will filter your source data sooner than my first option so performance wise should be better.

Final option is to use a source qualifier with sql override same as your current query... filters record out right at the database so a plus there (so long as the query itself is optimal) but sql overrides are not validated in the wider mapping context and can spring unexpected surprises so should be used with a lot of caution.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I still did not understood how to be possible achive "BETWEEN A.VON_ID AND A.BIS_ID" in a joiner condition, that is way for the second subquery I was going for a SQL Trasformation, but then it is not possible send input from 2 SQ(getting "concatenation disallowed on trasformation SQL" error)

Comment: I found a workaround for have the logic of the "between". Basically I used an SQL override in a Source qualifier. The incovenience that I face is still have something different form target table where in row SQL are temporary tables(in the end subquary for the SQL engine are that). Indeed I create a table for store the value coming from the inner subquery, that where are values from the lead function. Then I have to create another table for "store" value for the second subquery.

Comment: This does not look really performant to me, without meantion that I need to have those additional tables that normally I do not have in the schema. Any help here?

Comment: I'm not sure why you need to create temporary tables (am working on oracle db and haven't seen informatica creating temporary tables there)

Comment: Have you tried feeding the full sql as is into a source qualifier sql override i.e. not breaking into subqueries? Should be most performant option if you are able to tune your indexes on the source db.

Comment: I have tried that but for some reason was not working. I will try again though now I do have more knowledge of Informatica "errors"

Comment: Looking deeper into yoir query there are a couple of things that don't add up (and that you could do to make ot easier to analyse)... First I suspect you want to change A.ID = B.ID to

Comment: I suspect you want to change A.ID = B.ID to A.ID = B.ID (+) ... as if you get 2 consecutive numbers where SACHKONTO is not null then they won't get picked up in the outer query. There is the possibility for the subquery to return multiple records which match the outer query... this can be done with a lookup but only informatica 9.1 onward. Last, you've used A and B as aliases to represent 4 entities at the outer and subquery level... using A B C and D would make it much easier to analyse (and a bit more indentation too as I'm only on a cellphone these can make it a lot more difficult to read)

Comment: Daniel thank you for your analysis, I will have a much look at what you pointed out.

Comment: I put all the query in a SQL Trasformation and it was working(at least was executing without errors), but after few times  when back to that, now I am getting "Number of columns in the select query is greater than the number of output ports in the SQL transformation ", as far I remember it was working,ideed I have a mapping saved where I get a table fullfilled.I did checked and that error can comes for many reasons, as port mismatching, but in my case they are the same, or datatype mismatching, but also in this case they do match.

Comment: Hmmm is the query still selecting just 2 columns and can you take a screenshot of the ports?

Comment: it is the same indeed where the top query is selecting only 2 column. I am not sure I can upload in the comment, and also my implementation did change from the question, so not sure I can post it. Any suggestion?