# informatica-powercenter-better way to implement SQL “between” logic

Tags: etl, informatica, informatica-powercenter, data-integration

I have to implement a SQL statment with more than one subquery in Informatica PowerCenter.

In one of this I am stuck because I would use as suggested in another answer,2 Source Qualifier and then a Joiner Component, but I need to have the between condition as follow:

```
TableB.columnID BETWEEN TableA.columnID AND TableB.column_ID
```

Unfortunately I did not yet found a way to implement this condition that I so have in a where statement as you can see from the complete SQL.

More as far I know as far I know in PowerCenter the SQL transformation component cannot get imput from 2 Source Qualifiers.

The solution so far that I have found is to put the between condition in a SQL Override in Source Qualifier like in the image:

The all [SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41764196/informatica-multi-correlated-subquery-implementation) statment and my solution so far as a [SQL Override](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDp1I.png):

[image: SQL Override]

Answer (score 1):

Match criteria in joiner Can only be '='

If the join is not a 'full outer' you can use a lookup transformation configured to return ALL rows on match (not any, first or last)

Match criteria in lookups can be '>=', '<=', '<>' as well as'='.

There is a guide available here: https://dwbi.org/etl/informatica/139-active-lookup-transformation

Answer (score 0):

If you choose to use 2 source qualifiers and a joiner transformation, you can apply the between condition afterwards in a Filter transformation. You would have an expression like below in the filter transformation.

```
TableB_ID >= TableA_VON_ID AND TableB_ID <= TableB_BIS_ID
```

Comment: This is a Solution that should only be used on very small amounts of data,since a chartesian product will exist in DTM buffer memory between the joiner and the filter.